# How to receive data from MPI_BCast

Tags: mpi, parallel-processing

The problem is gravity interraction. There are N particles in a system and M processes.
I want to calculate new positions for particles(there are 11 parameters in all) in individual block in the current process and then broadcast new data to all the other processes.
Here is my code:

```
double * particles;
...
int startForProcess = numberOfParticlesPerThread * 11 * rank;
int endForProcess = startForProcess + numberOfParticlesPerThread * 11;
calculateNewPosition(particles, startForProcess, endForProcess, nParticles, rank);
MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
MPI_Bcast(particles+startForProcess, endForProcess - startForProcess, MPI_DOUBLE, rank, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

Unfortunately, in each thread I can see changes which were made only in this thread. There is no communication between processes.

Tell me please, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Let me get this straight: you want each process (MPI works with processes, not threads btw) to share its results with everyone else? `Bcast` is a one-to-all call, not all-to-all.

Comment: The MPI_Allgather answer by g.inozemtsev is the correct answer to your question, but you _really_ don't want to be doing this approach at all for production code; if you're planning on using this approach for a real n-body simulation there are other approaches which make use of the fact that more distant particles contribute less to the gravitational force - barnes-hut, fast multipole method, particle-mesh, etc.   Even for direct nbody calculators that do use the n^2 approach, they typically use "pipelining" type communciations approaches.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`MPI_Bcast` will broadcast data from the root to the rest of the ranks in the communicator.  All processes in an `MPI_Bcast` call must use the same root parameter, since they are all receiving data from the same process.

I think the function you are looking for is `MPI_Allgather`.  It will gather and propagate the updated data among all processes.

The code could look something like this:

```
double * particles;
double * my_particles;
...
int startForProcess = numberOfParticlesPerThread * 11 * rank;
int endForProcess = startForProcess + numberOfParticlesPerThread * 11;
calculateNewPosition(particles, startForProcess, endForProcess, nParticles, rank);

memcpy(my_particles, particles + startForProcess * sizeof(double),
       (endForProcess - startForProcess) * sizeof(double));
MPI_Allgather(my_particles, endForProcess - startForProcess, MPI_DOUBLE,
              particles, endForProcess - startForProcess, MPI_DOUBLE, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

As an aside, you don't need `MPI_Barrier` before a collective call, unless of course you need the synchronization for some other reason.

Comment: +1; slight correction though, the recvcount is per process, so it won't be `nParticles` it'll be the same `endForProcess-startForProcess` (=`numberOfParticlesPerThread`) as sendcount.